# How to enable Logger in Play framework v2.3 test?

Tags: scala, logging, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

The `Logger` in Play v2.3 test doesn't work:

```
"Test example" should {
  "Test 1" in {
    import play.api.Logger

    Logger.debug("hello world")  // doesn't work, no output on screen
  }
}
```

But if I wrap the test with `WithApplication`, it works:

```
"Test example" should {
  "Test 1" in new WithApplication {
    import play.api.Logger

    Logger.debug("hello world")
  }
}
```

But it gives overheads if I have to wrap every test with WithApplication just to make the Logger works.

So anyone know how to make the Logger works without WithApplication?

Comment: did you enabled logger from `application.conf`?

Comment: Are you using [`scalatestplus`](http://www.scalatest.org/plus/play)? If yes you can use [`OneServerPerSuite`](http://doc.scalatest.org/plus-play/1.0.0/index.html#org.scalatestplus.play.OneServerPerSuite) or `OneServerPerTest` traits which will bring a fake app to you context. It is a descent choice especially if you are already using [`scalatest`](http://www.scalatest.org).

Comment: @singhakash: yes, if not, the second test using `WithApplication` won't succeed. @Nader: I use built-in play test library which using specs2.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using scalatestplus you should override the FakeApplication additional configuration for the logger, here you have an example that is working

```
import org.scalatest._
import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import org.scalatestplus.play._

import play.api.Logger

class TestExampleLogger extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuite {

  // Override app if you need a FakeApplication with other than
  // default parameters.
  implicit override lazy val app: FakeApplication = FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = Map(
    "logger.application" -> "DEBUG"
  ))

  "Test example" should {
    "Test 1" in {
      import play.api.Logger

      Logger.debug("hello world")  // doesn't work, no output on screen
    }
  }

}
```

Hope it helps